# Use Actions as arguments

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm working on a Generic Effect class for making requests (other clasess will extend this one) and for making it generic I have to receive the 3 action types it uses) and I have an issue when passing the action types type:

```js
export interface ActionCreatorWithProps<TPropArgs extends object = {}>
  extends ActionCreator<string,
    (props: TPropArgs) => TPropArgs & TypedAction<string>
  > {
}

export interface EffectActions<S extends object, A extends object = {}, E extends object = {}> {
  startAction: ActionCreatorWithProps<A>;
  successAction: ActionCreatorWithProps<S>;
  errorAction: ActionCreatorWithProps<E>;
}

export abstract class RequestEffects<T extends object, A extends object = {}, E extends object = {}> {
///....
protected constructor(
    private requestEffectActions: RequestEffectActions<T, A>) {
}

makeRequestEffect$= createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<ActionCreatorWithProps<A>>(this.requestEffectActions.startAction),
        concatMap(() => this.executeRequest().pipe(
            map((response) => {
              return this.requestEffectActions.successAction(response);

              // * just returning an action directly works, like return myAction();
              // ** casting as Action works too and there's no error
              // return this.requestEffectActions.successAction(response) as Action; 
            }),
          ),
        ))
    );
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable<T & TypedAction<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T & TypedAction<string>> & (T & TypedAction<string> extends ActionCreator<string, Creator<any[], object>> ? "ActionCreator cannot be dispatched. Did you forget to call the action creator function?" : unknown)'. 
  Type 'Observable<T & TypedAction<string>>' is not assignable to type 'T & TypedAction<string> extends ActionCreator<string, Creator<any[], object>> ? "ActionCreator cannot be dispatched. Did you forget to call the action creator function?" : unknown'.  effect_creator.d.ts(12, 103): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

The return type of `this.requestEffectActions.successAction(response)` is `T & TypedAction<string>` which is basicaly the same as executing the an action like `myAction()`.

Any idea of why I can't make it work with this? The code runs okay but type checking not.

I just want to undesrtand why it's not undestanding the return action `return this.requestEffectActions.successAction(response)`